# Problema con el formato de fechas

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo el siguiente formulario, el cual es para extraer las filas de una tabla que esten entre una determinada fecha:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Mostrar las ofertas creadas entre 2 fechas</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="fechas_oferta" novalidate>
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="fecha_inicial" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Fecha inicial</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="fecha_inicial" type="date" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('fecha_inicial') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="fecha_inicial" value="{{ old('fecha_inicial') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('fecha_inicial'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('fecha_inicial') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="fecha_final" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Fecha final</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="fecha_final" type="date" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('fecha_final') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="fecha_final" value="{{ old('fecha_final') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('fecha_final'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('fecha_final') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="sector" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Sector</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select id="sector" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('sector') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="sector" value="{{ old('sector') }}" required autofocus>
                                    @foreach($sectores as $sector)
                                        <option value="{{$sector->nombre}}">{{$sector->nombre}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

                                @if ($errors->has('sector'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('sector') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Generar PDF
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Y aqui es donde registro las filas que esten creadas entre estas fechas:

```
$ofertas=Oferta::where(date('d-m-Y', strtotime('created_at')),'>=',date('d-m-Y', strtotime($request->fecha_inicial)))->where(date('d-m-Y', strtotime('created_at')),'<=',date('d-m-Y', strtotime($request->fecha_final)))->where('sector',$request->sector)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

Sin embargo, me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito pasar el formato de `update_at` a simplemente "año-mes-dia", ya que me hara más facil hacer las comparaciones.
¿Como lo logro?

Edito: He tenido una idea.
Esta es la tabla Oferta:

```
Schema::create('ofertas', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('titulo');
        $table->text('descripcion');
        $table->string('empresa');
        $table->string('sector');
        $table->date('fecha_limite');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Gracias al "timestamp" obtengo la variable created_at (que tiene formato `año-mes-dia hora-minuto-segundo`) con la que comparo fechas. Mi idea es quitar esta variable y sustituirla por un date que llamare 'fecha_creacion' (que solo tendra formato `año-mes-dia`). La historia es como hare desde ese entonces para poder insertar o modificar en la tabla sin que salte un mensaje de error porque faltan los atributos predefinidos de las fechas de creación y modificación.
De no ser posible, la alternativa es cambiar el formato de la variable created_at, para que muestre solo el año, el mes y el dia, pero no la hora, el minuto ni el segundo.

Comment: Si en tu query usas este formato `where('created_at','>=',strtotime($request->fecha_inicial)` ¿te da error?

Comment: @LeviArista Tambien da error en esa forma. Lo que me ocurre es que tengo una columna de una tabla con formato "año-mes-dia hora-minuto-segundo" y quiero que solo se muestre la parte de "año-mes-dia".

Comment: Claro, pero intenta primero hacer el filtro a nivel de base de datos y luego ya cambias el formato

Answer (score 0):

Ya he encontrado una solución. Presten atención a este código:

```
$ofertas=Oferta::whereDate('created_at','>=',$request->fecha_inicial)->whereDate('created_at','<=',$request->fecha_final)->where('sector',$request->sector)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

Al utilizar whereDate en lugar de un where a secas, automaticamente se formatean las variables a "año-mes-dia", permitiendo al fin hacer la comparación.